# Capture value of Textbox when OnChange is defined in the textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamically generated grid with x number of textboxes that will be in it.  As each textbox is generated, I give it an OnChange event that is a set function.

```
Html.TextBox(... new { @onchange = "ChangeItemQuantity(" + vm.ID + ", " + fk.id + ")" ...
```

So when it's rendered, it looks like this:

```
<input ... type="text" onchange="ChangeItemQuantity(1939, 3)" />
```

Then, in the script section:

```
function ChangeItemQuantity(ItemId, ForeignKeyId) {
    ...
}
```

In the ChangeItemQuantity() function, how would I also capture the new value of the textbox?  I don't really want to use an id on the textbox, because it is part of a grid with many textboxes.

Should I pass it in as a parameter?  If so, what would the syntax be of the code that renders the textbox?

Or, is there a way to capture is inside the javascript function?

Thanks!

Comment: `@Html.TextBox(.... new { @class="abc" data-id="...", data-fk="..." })` and `$('.abc').change(function() { var value = $(this).val(); var id = $(this).data('id'); var fk = $(this).data('fk'); .....`

Comment: Recommend you also read [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data in the html element why not use data- attributes?

Set them like so

```
@Html.TextBox(.... new { @class="someClass" data-vmId="vm.ID", data-fkId="fk.id" })
```

Then set a listener on that class

```
$('.someClass').change(function() { 
     var value = $(this).val(); 
     var vmid = $(this).data('vmid');
     var fkid = $(this).data('fkid');
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733589/textbox-class-onchange-event-listener-not-working-with-multiple-classes/40733672?noredirect=1#comment68694142_40733672

Comment: I posted a new question with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734094/how-to-capture-the-value-of-a-textbox-from-an-onchange-event