# Textbox Class Onchange Event Listener Not Working with Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, onchange

```
<input class="item-quantities valid" data-bomid="1939" data-rid="2054" id="AddedItemIDs_1939_" name="AddedItemIDs[1939]" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" value="7" aria-invalid="false">
```

Can't get this to work. What I've tried...

```
$('.item-quantities, .valid').change(function () {
            alert("we are here");
});
```

or...

```
$('.item-quantities.valid').change(function () {
            alert("we are here");
});
```

or...

```
$('.item-quantities').change(function () {
            alert("we are here");
});
```

... and a few other variations.

Can't seem to figure out how to trigger this event.  I've been playing around with various variations of $('.item-quantities, .valid'), to no avail.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: change event only fires when focus out from the field

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".item-quantities").change(function () {
                        alert("we are here");
            });
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input id="items" class="item-quantities valid" type="text">
    </body>
<html>
```

That will do the trick for classes

Comment: Yeah, I should have said that this textbox is generated inside of a grid, so it's any one of many textboxes, and I won't know the actual id.

Comment: Is this a dot net app?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $(".item-quantities").change(function () {
            alert("we are here");
   });
     });
  
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <input id="items" class="item-quantities valid" type="text">
 </body>
<html>

Comment: Always put all jQuery code within a script tag and wrap the within $( document ).read(function(){});

Comment: I already have it wrapped in document.ready.  I posted a new thread with more details.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734094/how-to-capture-the-value-of-a-textbox-from-an-onchange-event

Answer (score 0):

You can use oninput and onkeypress event like this: [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/19/)

```
    $('.item-quantities, .valid').on('input',function(e){
         alert("we are here")
        });

$('.item-quantities, .valid').on('change keypress', function(e){
         alert("we are xfgdfgdgdfg")
        });
```

Or like this

```
<input class="item-quantities valid" type="text" onchange="yourFunction();"
onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange(); onkeypress=this.onchange()" oninput="this.onchange();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.item-quantities.valid').change(function () {
    alert("we are here");
});
```

But change event of text only fires on its focus lost, its better to use keypress or keydown

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/12/)

Comment: The fiddle does indeed work.  But this solution isn't working on my page.  Hrmmm!!

Comment: It DOES work in the fiddle.  But for some reason it doesn't work on my page.