# How to capture the value of a textbox from an OnChange event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox

In my C# MVC app, I have a series of textboxes that are generated as such...

```
@foreach (object item in items) 
{ 
    @Html.TextBox(....)
}
```

The rendered result is a series of text boxes that look like this....

```
<input class="item-quantities valid" data-bomid="1939" data-rid="2054" id="AddedItemIDs_1939_" name="AddedItemIDs[1939]" onchange="ChangeItemQuantity(156,78)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" value="7" aria-invalid="false">

<input class="item-quantities valid" data-bomid="1940" data-rid="1055" id="AddedItemIDs_1940_" name="AddedItemIDs[1940]" onchange="ChangeItemQuantity(159,90)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" value="1">
```

Now, I need a javascript / jquery function in which I can capture three values:

1. bomid
2. rid
3. the new value of the textbox

I am just fine capturing the value when the textbox loses focus (tab out, etc.)

I have tried this (WITHOUT onchange="ChangeItemQuantity()" in the textbox), but for some reason I can never get this event to fire.  Plus, I'd rather NOT do it this way, because then I am forced to be rigid on what classes I assign to the textboxes....

```
    $(function () {
        $('.item-quantities.valid').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val(); 
            var bomid= $(this).data('bomid');
            var rid= $(this).data('rid');
        });
    });
```

And I have tried this (WITH onchange="ChangeItemQuantity(159,90)" in the textbox).  I would RATHER do it this way, as it allows me to be flexible with the classes in the text box...

```
function ChangeItemQuantity(bomid, rid) {
    // no idea how I would capture the value here.
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the captured values? Are you implementing some sort of VM store or is this updating your model via ajax?

Comment: updating model via ajax.  That part I'm not worried about.  It's just getting the values that is causing me trouble right now.  And not even the valueS.  Just the actual value of the textbox.

Comment: I wish people would explain their down votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another argument to the function to pass the element in and get it's `value`:

```
 onchange="ChangeItemQuantity(156,78, this)"

function ChangeItemQuantity(bomid, rid, el) {
    alert(el.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the attribute's value like this,

```
function getValues(){
var actual=$(this).value;
var bomid=$(this).attr('bomid');
var rid=$(this).attr('rid');
}
```